# Not rendered nested screen by react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

While I have a flat navigation like this

```
const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({
  Map: { 
    screen: MapScreen
  },
  RoadObject: { 
    screen: RoadObjectScreen
  }
});
```

class RoadObjectScreen is rendered every time when it is navigated to.

```
class RoadObjectScreen extends Component {

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.roadObject,
    tabBarVisible: false
});

render() {
    console.log('Navigation:', this.props.navigation);
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={{ paddingTop: 100 }} onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
                Welcome to {navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.roadObject }
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

BUT when I get screen nested, it stops to be rendered, just one at start of application. So console.log('Navigation:', this.props.navigation); popups just once.

```
const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({

  Map: { 
    screen: MapScreen, 
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarVisible: false
    }
  },
  RoadObjectMain: {
    screen: StackNavigator({
      RoadObject: { 
        screen: RoadObjectScreen
      }
    }) 
  }
});
```

Why does it happen? How get I get it rendered and get this.props.navigation accessable.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `TabNavigator`, tabs render once when the navigator is mounted so when you switch between tabs the screens will not be rendered a second time.

Although they are not rendering second time you can still access `this.props.navigation` in your class.

If you want your tabs to be rendered only when you switch to that tab, you can use [`lazy`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#TabNavigatorConfig) prop. This will make your tabs render when they are switched but they will be rendered only once unless there is any change in state or props for that screen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, bennygenel! But how can I catch changes in this.props.navigation in the RoadObject (StackNavigator, not TabNavigator as you mentioned). What function is run when this screen is activated?

Comment: Unless there is no change in that screen no function will be triggered. If you change any state or props value, `componentWillReceiveProps` will be fired. For more info you can see [component life-cycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)